# angular2 - how to simulate error on http.post unit test

Tags: unit-testing, http, post, angular

I m writing a Uni-test for a login Method with an HTTP.post call, like:

```
this.http.post( endpoint, creds, { headers: headers})
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
        data => this.onLoginComplete(data.access_token, credentials),  
        err => this.onHttpLoginFailed(err),
        () => this.trace.debug(this.componentName, "Login completed.")
    );
```

The problem is that i'm not able to simulate the error branch; everytime is called the onLoginComplete Method;

here is my test:

```
it("check that  Atfer Login, console show an error ", inject(
  [TraceService, Http, MockBackend, WsiEndpointService],
  (traceService: TraceService, http: Http, 
   backend: MockBackend, wsiEndpoint: WsiEndpointService) => {

  let tokenTest: number =  404 ;

  let response: ResponseOptions = null {} // i think i have to modify this

  let connection: any;

  backend.connections.subscribe((c: any) => connection = c);

  let authService: AuthService = new AuthService(http, Service1, Service2);

  authenticationservice.login({ "username": "a", "password": "1" });

  connection.mockRespond(new Response(response));

  expect(ERROR);

}));
```

Thanks again to everyone.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First you need to override the `XHRBackend` class by the `MockBackend` one:

```
describe('HttpService Tests', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => {
    return [
      HTTP_PROVIDERS,
      provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: MockBackend }),
      HttpService
    ];
  });

  (...)
});
```

Notice that `HttpService` is the service that uses the `Http` object and I want to test.

Then you need to inject the mockBackend and subscribe on its `connections` property. When a request is sent, the corresponding callback is called and you can specify the response elements like the body. The service will receive this response as the response of the call. So you'll be able to test your service method based on this.

Below I describe how to test the `getItems` method of the `HttpService`:

```
it('Should return a list of items', inject([XHRBackend, HttpService, Injector], (mockBackend, httpService, injector) => {
  mockBackend.connections.subscribe(
    (connection: MockConnection) => {
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(
        new ResponseOptions({
          body: [ { id: '1', label: 'item1' }]
        })));
      });

  httpService.getItems().subscribe(
    items => {
      expect(items).toEqual([ { id: '1', label: 'item1' }]);
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the code of `getItems` method of the `HttpService`:

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {
  constructor(private http:Http) {
  }

  getItems(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get('/items').map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

To simulate an error simply use the `mockError` method instead of the `mockResponse`one:

```
  mockBackend.connections.subscribe(
    (connection: MockConnection) => {
      connection.mockError(new Error('some error'));
    });
```

Comment: Small question: How would you add an error http status code (404, 422, 500, etc) with mockError, besides the string? In my case, some server responses won't return anything but that. For some reason I haven't found an example that shows that anywhere.

Comment: @LucioMollinedo that's because it's not supported in current RC. See https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/8961 for the bug fix to make this available. In the meantime, poor unit tests going to have to take another hit.

Comment: I am wondering whether this solution can be applied to the current version of angular (2.4)? I tried to adapt it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42192911/ to no avail... Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 2):

You can simulate an error like this:

```
connection.mockError(new Response(new ResponseOptions({
    body: '',
    status: 404,
})));
```

I created a small class

```
import {ResponseOptions, Response} from '@angular/http';

export class MockError extends Response implements Error {

    name: any;
    message: any;

    constructor(status: number, body: string = '') {
        super(new ResponseOptions({status, body}));
    }
}
```

which can use like this

```
connection.mockError(new MockError(404));
```