# Issue with jasmine expectations not being tested/evaluated because of simulated mock error

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular2-testing

I am trying to unit test a angular 2 component and simulate an error (400/bad request) from the http backend.

Here is my code:

```js
describe('Component: UserAccountActivationComponent', () => {

  let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserAccountActivationComponent>;
  let userAccountActivationComponent: UserAccountActivationComponent;
  const observableMock = Observable.of('Some Observable');

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: (backend, options) => new Http(backend, options),
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        },
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute, useClass: RouteMock
        },
      ],
      imports: [AppModule, HttpModule]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserAccountActivationComponent);
    userAccountActivationComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it('should not signin user nor navigate to dashboard if account is not activated', fakeAsync(inject(
    [UserAccountService, SessionSigninService, Router, MockBackend],
    (userAccountService: UserAccountService, signinService: SessionSigninService, router: Router, mockBackend: MockBackend) => {

      const opts = {
        type: ResponseType.Error,
        status: 400
      };
      const responseOpts = new ResponseOptions(opts);

      mockBackend.connections.subscribe(
        (connection: MockConnection) => {
          connection.mockError(new MockError(responseOpts));
        });

      const activateSpy = spyOn(userAccountService, 'activateAccount').and.callThrough();
      const signinSpy = spyOn(signinService, 'signinByUserAccountToken').and.returnValue(observableMock);
      const navigateSpy = spyOn(router, 'navigate').and.returnValue(observableMock);

      fixture.detectChanges();
      tick();

      expect(activateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(signinSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(navigateSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    })));

});

class MockError extends Response implements Error {
  name: any;
  message: any;
}

class RouteMock {
  readonly params = Observable.of({userAccountToken: 'a-token'});
}
```

I am simulating an error occurring in the `userAccountService.activateAccount` method. I just want to check that neither `signinService.signinByUserAccountToken` nor the `router.navigate` are called. This is what I am trying to do with the jasmine expectations:

```js
  expect(activateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(signinSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(navigateSpy).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
```

However, I the test is stopped by the simulated error:

```js
Chrome 56.0.2924 (Mac OS X 10.12.3) Component: UserAccountActivationComponent should not signin user nor navigate to dashboard if account is not activated FAILED
    Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Response with status: 400 null for URL: null
        at ViewWrappedError.ZoneAwareError (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:811:0 <- src/test.ts:142448:33)
        at ViewWrappedError.BaseError [as constructor] (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/facade/errors.js:22:0 <- src/test.ts:36304:16)
        at ViewWrappedError.WrappedError [as constructor] (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/facade/errors.js:87:0 <- src/test.ts:36369:16)
        at new ViewWrappedError (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/errors.js:77:0 <- src/test.ts:70405:16)
        at proxyClass.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:653:0 <- src/test.ts:111685:23)
        at proxyClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:626:0 <- src/test.ts:111658:18)
        at ViewRef_.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view_ref.js:170:0 <- src/test.ts:71336:20)
        at ComponentFixture._tick (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:196:0 <- src/test.ts:15653:36)
        at webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:210:45 <- src/test.ts:15667:53
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:242:0 <- src/test.ts:141879:26)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- src/test.ts:98996:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:241:0 <- src/test.ts:141878:32)
        at Object.onInvoke (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone.js:271:0 <- src/test.ts:38049:37)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:241:0 <- src/test.ts:141878:32)
        at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:0 <- src/test.ts:141750:43)
```

FYI, here is the component under test:

```js
@Component({
  templateUrl: './useraccount-activation.component.html'
})
export class UserAccountActivationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userAccountService: UserAccountService,
              private signinService: SessionSigninService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.params
      .take(1)
      .pluck('userAccountToken')
      .switchMap((userAccountToken: string) =>
        this.userAccountService.activateAccount(userAccountToken)
          .switchMapTo(this.signinService.signinByUserAccountToken(userAccountToken))
      )
      .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']));
  }
}
```

**edit 1**: Unfortunately, changing to:

```js
  mockBackend.connections.subscribe(
    (connection: MockConnection) => {
      responseOpts.url = connection.request.url;
      connection.mockError(new MockError(responseOpts));
    });
```

Still causes the following error:

```js
'HttpClient error: ', MockError{_body: null, status: 400, ok: false, statusText: null, headers: null, type: 3, url: '/api/useraccount/activate/a-valid-token'}

    Error: Error in :0:0 caused by: Response with status: 400 null for URL: /api/useraccount/activate/a-valid-token
        at Error.ZoneAwareError (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:958:0 <- src/test.ts:143513:33)
        at ZoneAwareError (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:955:0 <- src/test.ts:143510:35)
        at wrappedError (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/error_handler.js:144:21 <- src/test.ts:36697:34)
        at viewWrappedError (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/errors.js:65:21 <- src/test.ts:70785:125)
        at proxyClass.DebugAppView._rethrowWithContext (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:656:0 <- src/test.ts:112336:111)
        at proxyClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:629:0 <- src/test.ts:112309:18)
        at ViewRef_.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view_ref.js:172:0 <- src/test.ts:71715:20)
        at ComponentFixture._tick (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:196:0 <- src/test.ts:15805:36)
        at webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:210:45 <- src/test.ts:15819:53
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:330:0 <- src/test.ts:142885:26)
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- src/test.ts:99788:39)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:329:0 <- src/test.ts:142884:32)
        at Object.onInvoke (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone.js:273:0 <- src/test.ts:38516:37)
        at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:329:0 <- src/test.ts:142884:32)
        at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:126:0 <- src/test.ts:142681:43)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are getting the exception because the `Url` is not specified. Try setting the url on the options like so:

```js
let responseOpts = new ResponseOptions(opts);

mockBackend.connections.subscribe(
  (connection: MockConnection) => {
    responseOpts.url = connection.request.url;
    connection.mockError(new MockError(responseOpts));
});
```

#### Edit 1

The issue you are seeing might be because the error is not being caught anywhere and so it is bubbling up to zone. Try adding an error catch to your subscribe to handle exceptions or squelch the error, `(error) => {}`.

```
this.route.params
  .take(1)
  .pluck('userAccountToken')
  .switchMap((userAccountToken: string) =>
    this.userAccountService.activateAccount(userAccountToken)
      .switchMapTo(this.signinService.signinByUserAccountToken(userAccountToken))
  )
  .subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']), (error) => {});
```

Comment: Hi Teddy, Unfortunately, the change you suggested does not prevent the test to be halted by the error... Any other suggestion?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: It is definitely due to the error bubbling up to zone. You're right. I tried swallowing the error as you suggested but the issue is that I am modifying production code here... I am sure there is a way to simulate the error by fixing the test itself. Furthermore, the `signinByUserAccount` is still invoked...

Comment: `signinByUserAccount` will be called everytime because of how the observable is set up. The `switchMap` and `switchMapTo` chain the observables together which means they will all be called during the observable pipeline. Furthermore, if it is not reasonable to catch the error in the production code then there is no reason to create a test that causes an error. If the method were to error when in production then the error would be propagated to the page if there was no catch for the error case.

Comment: @balteo does the above make sense?

Comment: Sorry I did not reply before. Yes it does make sense. I guess I need to somehow rethink error management in my app together with the way I test it. This might require opening another question.

Comment: Your reply is relevant and exact although it does not fully solve my problem. I will still upvote it and award the bounty. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome. If you create a new question post a link here and I will take a look at it.

Comment: OK. Will do so.